# How to move minimize maximize and close button to left in ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10

How to move minimize maximize and close button to left in ubuntu 17.10?
I want them like in old days.

.

Comment: ```gsettings set  org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:' ```  this works fine on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 14):

Got answer from https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2348381

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout close,minimize,maximize:
```

Answer (score 12):

Use ‘Gnome Tweaks’ (found in "Software"). Apart from this setting, you can customize lots of the Gnome settings in this app, which is **essential** to the Gnome DE / Shell IMVHO.
After installing, just go to the "Windows" tab and scroll to the end to find the switch for left/right position of the buttons.

[image: Screenshot]