# What is the reason for the switching 'X' button spot?

Tags: 16.04, 17.10, interface

I have used ubuntu with an interface of the left top 'X' button.

In 17.10, it has been switched to the right top.

It is wondered why.

Comment: Opinion based questions are not supported here. If you're looking for a way to change positions of those buttons, it's a possible duplicate of [How to switch window controls to the left (Gnome Shell)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9867/how-to-switch-window-controls-to-the-left-gnome-shell) Or follow this answer for a simple fix: https://askubuntu.com/a/975432/480481

Comment: You may read this article for some insight: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/08/ubuntu-moves-window-controls-right